# WCF Service Client Exception

Tags: vb.net, wcf, service

I have a WCF service which is referencing other WCF service as client. I have a function with this code:

```
Dim _login As New LoginWCFService.LoginClient
```

`LoginClient` is the service that I want to use. When execute this code I have always this error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'ServiceLogin.ILogin' in the ServiceModel client configuration
>   section.

What may be happening?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing the configuration for that contract in your config file (app.config or web.config) in the `system.serviceModel` part.

Comment: Thanks Styxxy, solved!